# How do I merge logs from multiple Magento nodes?

Tags: magento, merge, logging

What is the best way to merge the system and exception logs from multiple load-balanced Magento nodes onto a separate server?

Answer (score 0):

mounting var/log on an NFS share or other remote location should work for you.